# Webstorm 8 Smarty plugin

Tags: smarty, webstorm

I try use [Shopware plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7410?pr=phpStorm) but it requires [Symfony2 Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219).
But it raise this: [image: error]

com.jetbrains.php links to [Php Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610)
But when I try install it, I have this error: [image: error2]

Webstorm version: 8.0.4

Tried PHP plugin: 138.1161 and 138.826

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm doesn't have PHP support, that is why you can't use Symfony2 plugin. Use [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) instead of WebStorm.